Is there a security issue or downside with using pam_succeed_if to enable automatic login?
Consider adding a line
auth succeed pam_succeed_if.so tty = /dev/ttyS0

to /etc/pam.d/login before @include common-auth. The desired effect would be password-less login via /dev/ttyS0 for root (but it really authenticates every user). This can be useful when configured in a virtual machine e.g. via libvirt such that virsh console gives you access without having to type a password in a similar way that attaching a container does not require a password.
Is there an downside, security issue or unintended side effect with this configuration? Is there a plausible scenario where this configuration causes a privilege escalation?

While the example of using pam_succeed_if.so to allow automatic login avoids the problem of being forced to input a password when working with virtual machines or containers, various security assumptions must be considered and the huge potential drawbacks of this method. There are some pretty substantial risks in this approach.

The obvious: Bypassing Authentication:

When a user is allowed to automatically log in without entering a password, the system bypasses the regular mechanism of authentication. This, in turn, increases the risk of security violation and intrusion.


Privilege Escalation:

As previously mentioned, the configuration suggested the login of the root user which opens up vulnerability.


Lack of Accountability:

No authentication means lower accountability. Users are not obliged to prove their identity towards the system.


Possible Vulnerability Exploitation:

Inconsistent security practice led by the illusion of safety, automatic login lines up the pretext of less protective behavior in the system or an organization.


Inconsistent Delivery of Security Measures:

In case of the possible combination of incongruous events, automatic login may hold unauthenticated events in case something happens to the account primary entry.



Overall, automatic login may seem like a cool and convenient feature, especially in cases when the operator indeed has nothing to hide or is indeed the only user. Your opening a whole can of worms.

Can you add detail to your threat model? We already have authentication bypass as the one being able to access the system console can also access the unencrypted disk image assuming lack of confidential computing support. What kind of vulnerability do you see precisely? Why is it not a vulnerability for containers where this is common practice?
